# added entry to hosts file (ubuntu); can ping ok; cannot nslookup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server

added entry to /etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1    testjd.com
```

can ping ok

```
ping testjd.com

PING test.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
```

but nslookup (and apache2 config) can't resolve the new name...

```
nslookup testjd.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name > -- ignoring!
```

note: cat /etc/host.conf

```
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

what i ultimately want to achieve is for my apache2 config to be able to resolve the new local name (note: i configured a virtualhost for testjd.com, but i can't get past the "resolve host name" problem shown above)

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `nslookup` command works with a DNS, and your DNS can't find testjd.com. You can use the `host` command instead, which will interact with your hosts file.

```
john@awesome:~$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
```

Comment: tried "host testjd.com" and also got "no servers could be reached" 
what i ultimately want to achieve is for my apache2 config to be able to resolve the new local name. thanks.

Comment: I think what you want is a VirtualHost: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: you're right; i already configured the virtualhost for testjd.com (should have been more clear); but that's where my name resolution problems started (which led to trying nslookup; i was thinking that if i fix the nslookup problem, then that'll take care of the apache problem as well))

Comment: Can you post your vhost config? also what is the output of `apachectl -t`?

Comment: output for apache2ctl -t : "[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name" --- and finally "Syntax OK"

Comment: @openjd sorry for the delayed response, was a little busy. Could you pastebin your entire httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

To use both the `hosts` file and a DNS Server, use `getent`. For example:

`getent ahosts <hostname>`

---

Notes:

- As John T answered, `nslookup` will use a DNS server and the `/etc/hosts` file is not a DNS server
- DNS configuration can be found in `/etc/resolv.conf`
- Name service (including the `hosts` file) can be found at `/etc/nsswitch.conf`